# HTTP headers format using python's requests

Tags: python-3.x, http, request, header, python-requests

I use python requests to capture a website's http headers. For example, this is a response header:

> {'Connection': 'keep-alive',
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'cache-control': 'max-age=600',
>   'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Expires': 'Fri, 19 Apr
>   2019 03:16:28 GMT', 'Via': '1.1 varnish, 1.1 varnish', 'X-ESI': 'on',
>   'Verso': 'false', 'Accept-Ranges': 'none', 'Date': 'Fri, 19 Apr 2019
>   03:11:12 GMT', 'Age': '283', 'Set-Cookie':
>   'CN_xid=08f66bff-4001-4173-b4e2-71ac31bb58d7; Expires=Wed, 16 Oct 2019
>   03:11:12 GMT; path=/;, xid1=1; Expires=Fri, 19 Apr 2019 03:11:27 GMT;
>   path=/;, verso_bucket=281; Expires=Sat, 18 Apr 2020 03:11:12 GMT;
>   path=/;', 'X-Served-By': 'cache-iad2133-IAD, cache-gru17122-GRU',
>   'X-Cache': 'HIT, MISS', 'X-Cache-Hits': '1, 0', 'X-Timer':
>   'S1555643472.999490,VS0,VE302', 'Content-Security-Policy':
>   "default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; child-src
>   https: data: blob:; connect-src https: data: blob:; font-src https:
>   data:; img-src https: data: blob:; media-src https: data: blob:;
>   object-src https:; script-src https: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'
>   'unsafe-eval'; style-src https: 'unsafe-inline';
>   block-all-mixed-content; upgrade-insecure-requests; report-uri
>   https://l.com/csp/gq",
>   'X-Fastly-Device-Detect': 'desktop', 'Strict-Transport-Security':
>   'max-age=7776000; preload', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding, Verso,
>   Accept-Encoding', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'transfer-encoding':
>   'chunked'}

I noted that from several examples I tested, the headers I receive from `requests` are formatted as `'key':'value'` (plz note the single colons surrounding the key and the value). However, when I check the headers from the Firefox-> Web developer -> Inspector, and choose to view the header in raw format, I do not see commas:

> HTTP/2.0 200 OK date: Thu, 09 May 2019 18:49:07 GMT expires: -1
>   cache-control: private, max-age=0 content-type: text/html;
>   charset=UTF-8 strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
>   content-encoding: br server: gws content-length: 55844
>   x-xss-protection: 0 x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN set-cookie:
>   1P_JAR=2019-05-09-18; expires=Sat, 08-Jun-2019 18:49:07 GMT; path=/;
>   domain=.google.com alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39"
>   X-Firefox-Spdy: h2

I need to know: Does python's `requests` module always adds single colons? This important from me as I need to include/exclude them in my regex that is used to analyze the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I think you are running into is the request coming back as a `dict` instead of a value as firefox inspector is giving you.  When you do this you could be getting mixed results if one of the value pairs has a numeric or boolean value so when doing your regex you may want to use a Try/Except if you can remove the exterior apostrophes or just use the value given.

Comment: If you really want the quotes you can do a ```s.replace("'", '"')``` (Spaces added to show differences).  When looking up the values though you can just use request['Connection'] to get the values you need anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the requests module that's adding the colons.  Request represents headers as a dict, but you seem to be treating them as a string.  When Python converts dicts to strings, they get the colons, the commas, the quotation marks.

The right fix for your program is probably to treat the dictionary as a dictionary, not convert it into a string.  But if you really want the headers in string form, you should consider using different tool, such as curl.

Comment: The header is inside a string field in the database. So I have to treat it as a string. Is it a big problem? I think I can just consider the quotes.

Comment: The dict string format isn't meant for data storage / exchange.  If you're storing it in a database, it's best to convert it to JSON first.  Also, be aware that the quotes may be single quotes or double quotes, depending on the content of the string.

Comment: Things are much complicated. It is a big data. It is already in the database. I prefer not to change unless no solution. I do not get how converting it to json will help? The headers where read in a text file in csv file format, then inserted into the DB. I can always assume that there is a single or double quotes in each key/value ('|") beginning and end. Then thread what's inside them as normal. Do you see anything absolutely wrong in doing so?

Comment: Converting to JSON will help because JSON is intended to be a data interchange format, so it won't format things in inconsistent or surprising ways.  JSON has broad language support including many major databases, so you can probably construct SQL queries against JSON data.  What's wrong with just using the Python output as-is is that you can't depend on it to have consistent formatting, because that's not what that output format is designed for.